# Put a trigonometric equation in the form A*cos(theta)+B*sin(theta)+C=0

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

```
eq = (Cos[Θ[t]]cf - Cos[γ1[t]] mf + Cos[γ2[t]] mf)^2/cf^2 + (Sin[Θ[t]]cf + Sin[γ1[t]] mf - Sin[γ2[t]] mf + xP1[t] - xP2[t])^2/cf^2
```

Can you help me to simplify and put this trigonometric equation in the following form:

```
A*Cos[Θ[t]] + B*Sin[Θ[t]] + C == 0
```

I would like to extract `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Thanks a lot of for your help

Comment: I don't understand: what should happen to the gamma1 and gamma2 functions, since they don't appear in your desired form any longer?

Comment: Nothing because gamma1 and gamma2 are in my problem function a which are knowns. In problem only thêta is unknown

Comment: `A == 0, B== 0, C == eq`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Collect[Expand[eq] /. Sin[Θ[t]]^2 -> 1 - Cos[Θ[t]]^2, {Sin[Θ[t]], Cos[Θ[t]]}, Simplify]

(* (2 mf (-Cos[γ1[t]] + Cos[γ2[t]]) Cos[Θ[t]])/cf + 
   (2 Sin[Θ[t]] (mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) + xP1[t] - xP2[t]))/cf + 
   (cf^2 + 2 mf^2 - 2 mf^2 Cos[γ1[t] - γ2[t]] + xP1[t]^2 + 
    2 xP1[t] (mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) - xP2[t]) - 
    2 mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) xP2[t] + xP2[t]^2)/cf^2 *)
```

casts the expression into the desired form.  Use `Coefficient` to explicitly extract `A` and `B`.

```
a = Coefficient[%, Sin[Θ[t]]]
(* (2 (mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) + xP1[t] - xP2[t]))/cf *)
b = Coefficient[%%, Cos[Θ[t]]]
(* (2 mf (-Cos[γ1[t]] + Cos[γ2[t]]))/cf *)
c = %%% /. {Sin[Θ[t]] -> 0, Cos[Θ[t]] -> 0}
(* (cf^2 + 2 mf^2 - 2 mf^2 Cos[γ1[t] - γ2[t]] + xP1[t]^2 + 
   2 xP1[t] (mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) - xP2[t]) - 
   2 mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) xP2[t] + xP2[t]^2)/cf^2 *)
```

Comment: It works perfectly for a and b but for c I receive the following error message :

c = SommeCarreSimp /. {Sin[Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], 2][t]] -> 0, 
   Cos[Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], 2][t]] -> 0}

$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Hold[1/
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(c\), \(f\), \(2\)]\)]

Do you have an idea about this error message ?

Comment: @Bendesarts  I suggest you restart Mathematica, recopy the code from my answer and run again.  You may have some old definitions in memory.

Answer (score 5):

`{A, B}` is given by

```
fc = FourierCoefficient[eq, Θ[t], -1];
2 ReIm@fc // ComplexExpand     (* {A, B *)
```

and `C`, which of course you already know you should avoid using, by

```
eq - 2 ReIm@fc.{Cos[Θ[t]], Sin[Θ[t]]} // 
  ComplexExpand // Simplify
(*
  (1/(cf^2))(cf^2 + 2 mf^2 - 2 mf^2 Cos[γ1[t] - γ2[t]] + 
    xP1[t]^2 + 
    2 xP1[t] (mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) - xP2[t]) - 
    2 mf (Sin[γ1[t]] - Sin[γ2[t]]) xP2[t] + xP2[t]^2)
*)
```

Comment: Novel approach (+1).